# Запрос с https на http

Tags: http, https, браузер

Возможно ли заставить сделать браузер запрос с https на http?

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, какой именно запрос имеется в виду

Comment: Впрочем, в любом случае браузеры нынче двигаются в сторону полного запрета

Comment: @andreymal я понимаю. Мне нужно это выкатить, потому что горит. Дальше буду править